# Content of file is displayed wrong on webpage. How can I convert it to right charset?

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I got a Textfile with some content. The creator told me its in UTF-8. Later I want to show the content at a webpage which is using `charset=utf-8`, but it seems like the content is encoded with a different charset.

In the Textfile and at the webpage it looks like this (1):

[image]

But it should look like this (2):

```
• more time. Drive with Sozius…%4
```

When I do the following steps I'm able to show the content in the right format:

- Using the followinh php code on the content `iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $txt)`
- Change charset of webpage to `charset=ISO-8859-1"`

Now the content of the file is displayed as example (2) at the webpage. But I cannot change the charset of the webpage. Is there any way to convert the string in php so that it's displayed right at the UTF-8 encoded webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `mb_detect_encoding` ?

You can do something like :

```
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($string);
if ('UTF-8' !== $encoding) {
  $convertedString = iconv($encoding, 'UTF-8', $string);
}
```

Comment: mb_detect_encoding is detecting UTF-8, but even though its not showing want I want

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP page insert this [header](http://php.net/header) *before any output has been sent to the client*:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

And in the HTML of that web page insert this [meta](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp) tag:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Comment: Thats already the case. Its like the content of the file is no real UTF-8.